# Why was the payload placed on the rocket for a test?

Tags: launch, spacex, falcon-9, testing, payload

The payload for the Falcon 9, the Amos 6 satellite, was placed on top of the rocket during the static fire test. Why was this done?

Comment: Sigh, I thought I checked for dups... Oh well.

Comment: It saved them time and money